# Send jQuery variable by mail

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, email

I have a jQuery variable that contains HTML and values from a form. I would like to send it via email using a seperate php file with `@mail`.

I am trying to send this variable with the jQuery `$.ajax` function on form submit but it doesn't send the variable to the php file and therefore, no email is sent.

Here is my code

*jQuery :*

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var foo = '<p>Some message</p>';
    $.ajax({
        url: '/send.php',
        type: 'post', 
        data: {foo : foo},
        success: function() { 
            alert('email sent!');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

*send.php :*

```
<?php

    $email_to = "XXX";
    $email_from = "YYY";
    $email_message = $_POST["foo"];
    $email_subject = "[Email subject]";
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
```

I tried to `echo` the foo variable in send.php and removing `return false;` in the jQuery but The variable doesn't seem to pass to the file and nothing is displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe `data: {"foo": foo}` will help (I'm not sure)

Comment: @ciuak I tried that but it didn't work either

Comment: Use your browser tools to check what's being passed to the script; that may shed some light on the problem. You may be sending JSON data rather than POST data.

Comment: If you hardcode the `email_message`, does it actually send out the email fine ? If not, you might have to investigate that first

Comment: or maybe: `url: '/send.php?foo='+message` -- using GET?

Comment: @ciuak You'd need to include uri escaping in that, and may trip over URL-length limits.

Comment: Dont you think you should use `dataType: "json"`, parameter also.

Comment: @AdrianWragg in the header, the data seems to be sent but the php file fails to echo it.

Comment: @LearningAsp I tried adding `dataType: "json"` but it doesn't change anything

Comment: Is send.php in your root folder?

Comment: @putvande no but I don't get 404 error on my project so the path shouldn't be the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is OK! We are supposing your PHP web server is working, So the 2 only possible error are:

```
url: '/send.php'
```

Are you sure *send.php* is in the root of your domain? Like

```
http://localhost/send.php
```

The second possibility is that you a have a previous javascript fatal error, so your ajax lines will never be readed...

How to debug?

1 - Are your pages refreshing when you post your form? If yes, there's an previous error that prevents *return false;* to be readed

2 - You can press F12 in most of browsers to open developer tools, in this case the Network Panel is what you need: Just try your code with this panel opened and see what happens there... 404 error code  means "I cant find send.php!".

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/B7JZf/) gets a 404 because http://fiddle.jshell.net/send.php doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try This works for you.

```
<html>
   <body>  
        <form method="post" class="mailform" onsubmit="return false;">
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on('submit','form',function()
            {
                var foo = '<p>Some message</p>';
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'send.php',
                    type: 'post', 
                    data: {'foo' : foo},
                    success: function() { 
                        alert('email sent!');
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        </script>
   </body>
</html>
```